# Show $\exists !\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$ when $\mathbf{c}^Tf(\mathbf{x}) \equiv 0$, where $f$ is a vector function consisting of polynomials of $x_i$'s

Tags: analysis, power-series

For $\mathbf{x} = (x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_\nu) \in \mathbb{R}^\nu$, where $\nu = \max \{ j(1), \cdots, j(n) \} $, define $f :\mathbb{R}^\nu \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^n$ as follows.

$$
f(\mathbf{x} ) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{j(1)}x_i ,\sum_{i=1}^{j(2)} x_i^2, \sum_{i=1}^{j(3)} x_i^3, \cdots, \sum_{i=1}^{j(n)}x_i^n \right)
$$

Say $\exists \mathbf{c} = (c_1, \cdots, c_n) \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $\mathbf{c}^Tf(\mathbf{x}) \equiv 0$. I'm trying to show $\mathbf{c} = \mathbf{0}$, uniquely.

What comes to my mind is **uniqueness of power series**, but I'm not sure it can be thought of as "uniqueness of polynomial expansion".

P.S. maybe the problem can be trimmed more tidily, but I have no idea for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If:

$$
f(\mathbf{x} ) = \left( \sum_{i=1}^{j(1)}x_i ,\sum_{i=1}^{j(2)} x_i^2, \sum_{i=1}^{j(3)} x_i^3, \cdots, \sum_{i=1}^{j(n)}x_i^n \right)
$$

Then:

$$
c^T f(\mathbf{x} ) = c_1\sum_{i=1}^{j(1)}x_i + c_2\sum_{i=1}^{j(2)} x_i^2 + c_3\sum_{i=1}^{j(3)} x_i^3 + \cdots + c_n\sum_{i=1}^{j(n)}x_i^n 
$$

Then if:

$$
c^T f(\mathbf{x} ) \equiv 0
$$

For any $i$, $j$ we have:
$$
\frac{\partial ^i [c^T f(\mathbf{x} )]}{\partial x_j^i} \equiv 0
$$

For $i=n$:
$$
\frac{\partial ^n [c^T f(\mathbf{x} )]}{\partial x_j^n} = c_n\sum_{i=j}^{j} n! \equiv 0 \Rightarrow c_n=0
$$

Then we eliminate the last term in $c^T f(\mathbf{x} )$. By repeating until $n=1$ we conclude that $c$ is a null vector.